# Need to get 3D coordinates from 2 degree variables on sphere

Tags: 3d

this is kind of an odd one, and I'm not quite sure I'm asking at the right place, but here is goes:

let's say you have the following: (assuming everything is based around the point of origin) You have a degree of a circle ex: 90, and a radius, you want to get an X & Y from that.

Kind of the same thing, but on a sphere in 3D, I want to state 2 degrees and a radius and get x, y, z coordinates.

Comment: look into polar coordinates and Cartesian relation

Comment: @Moti thank you! perfect